# How does ctime change?

Tags: filesystem

I'm trying to precisely understand when the ctime timestamp of a file is changed. In many places (e.g., [in the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346852/how-to-modify-last-status-change-ctime-property-of-a-file-in-unix)) it is suggested that any change in the file attributes will also change ctime. However, this seems not to be true, at least on my Ubuntu 12.04 (yes, I know, a bit old...):

```
cat file.txt > /dev/null
```

changes the atime, so it changes the file attributes (in the file inode), but does not change the ctime.

Other sources (e.g., [here](http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime) and [here](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/04/atime-ctime-mtime-in-unix-filesystems/)) suggest that only some operations on the file attributes actually change the ctime, but a precise list is not provided.

Where may I find a precise reference to which operations change the ctime?

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to `cat`, did you examine it with `touch`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three time stamps on Unix systems:

- ### `atime`: Access time

  This time stamp tells you when the file was **accessed** the last time, including only reading access.
- ### `ctime`: Change time

  This time stamp tells you when the file **attributes (inode information) changed** the last time. That includes e.g ownership and permissions, but a content change also triggers an update of this time stamp.

  Note that changes to the **atime** seem to be an **exception** as they do not trigger a ctime update. This is probably because a simple read access which is enough to trigger an atime update does not make any relevant changes to the file attributes. And one of the main purposes of ctime is to help backup tools to determine if a file has changed. The atime is an irrelevant information for such tools and updating a backup just to update a changed atime because somebody has read the file would be useless.

  <del>I'm not sure, but some people think this behavior (changes to atime do not update ctime) is only due to the mount options (like `relatime`) of the underlying file system that caches and delays atime updates in the inode for performance reasons in memory and only applies them to the real inodes on the disk (triggering a ctime update) under certain conditions.</del>
  <sub>@kos tried it and apparently even when mounting a FS with the `strictatime``option, the ctime seems to never update if the atime changes.</sub>
- ### `mtime`: Modification time

  This time stamp tells you when the file's **content was modified** the last time.

---

So a simple read access using `cat FILENAME` only changes the **atime**, but not the **ctime** as no file attribute got modified. The changed **atime** does not count.

Comment: That's exactly the point: *why* the changed atime does not count? Isn't it a file attribute?

Comment: @VeryHardCoder I tried to elaborate my answer in that point and added some explanations.